# How to find hardware attached to Ubuntu OS using a C++ programs

Tags: c++, hardware

I want to list hardwares connected to my Ubuntu OS using a C++ programs. How to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [libudev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/).

Comment: I googled libudev and found this tutorial http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/.I tried to run the program http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/udev_example.c and received error for libudev-dev. After that I downloaded the udev library and tried to re compile the program and I am getting error for undefined references.

Comment: @CppLearner: Under Ubuntu you may use package manager to download&install libudev and libudev-dev. Then compile your program linking it with libudev, e.g. like in your tutorial - `#gcc -Wall -g -o udev_example udev_example.c -ludev`.